# Customise date range field Sonata Admin

Tags: php, symfony, filter, sonata-admin, sonata

I have `doctrine_orm_date_range` field with standart labels (start date and end date). How can i customise labels?

```
->add('creationDate', 'doctrine_orm_date_range',  array('label'  => 'list.creationDate'))
```

Comment: Hey, welcome to SO! Your question is very unclear, and needs some more explanation and context. Please show us what you are trying to achieve, and elaborate on what is stopping you from getting where you want to be. Add any errors you are getting. Good luck!

Comment: I mean wich attributies i need use for customise [labels](https://prnt.sc/i8olvv)?

p.s. Documentation didn't help me :(

Answer (score 0):

You can try this with datapicker plugin installed. For instance:

```
$datagridMapper

    // ...

    ->add('startedAt', 'doctrine_orm_date_range', [
        'field_type'                    => 'sonata_type_date_range_picker',
        'label'                         => 'admin.label.started_at',
        'translation_domain'            => 'admin',
    ])
```

Or:

```
$datagridMapper

    // ...

    ->add('date', 'doctrine_orm_date_range',[
        'input_type' => 'text',
        'field_options' => [
            'field_options_start' => [
                 'years'  => range(2011,2050),
                 'label' => 'Start Date',
            ],
            'field_options_end' => [
                 'years'  => range(2011,2050),
                 'label' => 'End Date',
            ]
        ],
        'label' => 'Date label'
    ])
```